# Deleting file from Bitbucket causing issue for ignored files

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket, gitignore

I performed number of steps (some mistakes and then correcting them as shown below) and it's now causing issue in Eclipse resulting in not allowing me to switch from master to branch1.

Below is the sequence of steps:

1. Created master branch and pushed code including .project file by
   mistake.
2. Created branch1 from master and pushed some code there.
3. Realizing mistake that .project file need not be committed, I switched back to master branch and used
   "git rm --cached .project" command to remove that file from repo. Though
   on terminal, it showed "rm '.project'", it would still show on bitbucked
   repo.
4. That gave me impression that the file was not removed from repo so I
   went to Bitbucket UI and removed that file externally from bitbucket
   (.project -> Edit -> Delete).
5. That deleted my file from repo.
6. Went back to Eclipse and made a pull request from Eclipse itself. No error was shown.

But now
    when I switch to branch1 from master, it's not allowing me to switch
    and shows the error:

[image: Eclipse shows error while switching from master to branch1]

I put that file in .gitignore file as well (by including `/.project`) and pushed `.gitignore` but in vain. It gives me options of "Reset", "Commit" and "Stash" but unfortunately none of them works probably cause git knows this file as "ignored file" / "untracked file". I tried all of them one by one (quite a few times) but this pops up all time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you see if you try to replicate these commands at the command line?  You should treat things like Eclipse and Bitbucket UIs as convenient wrappers; when things go wrong the first thing you should do is switch to the command line.

Comment: Also "*I keep pressing all of them*" - running random commands is a *great* way to ruin your repo.  Don't run a command if you don't know what it does.

Comment: @dimo414  "I keep pressing all of them" means I tried those buttons one by one but it keeps showing me that error again and again. I don't prefer to do something until I have its knowledge enough to keep my code safe.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you "tried those buttons", but it doesn't sound like you know what they're supposed to do.

Comment: @dimo414 Yps, that's probably words' game. I know meaning of those and committing was the last option but that also didn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the "ideal" answer but I think, from the command line, you could do a forced checkout of branch1 from master, do a git rm of the .project file and then push the change (the deletion of the .project file) to the remote repo. So it would look something like this:

```
git checkout -f branch1
git rm .project
git commit -m "Deleting .project dir"
git push origin branch1
```